# Find the number of solutions

Tags: number-theory, combinations

Find the number of solutions from $ a + b + c \leq x, $ being $ a, b, c $ natural

I used full combination and got it:

Using a slack variable that is a f variable, where f = x - (a + b + c), I think it comes out faster.
But I wanted to calculate the cases like:
$a + b + c = x$

$a + b + c = x - 1$
       
 .
        .
        .
$a + b + c = 0$

Then adding the solutions of each I arrived at what I sent before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a $d$ natural number, we can write $a+b+c+d=x$. So number of solutions the equation is $\dbinom{x+3}{3}$.

Comment: So that sum gives it?

Comment: Yes, the sum equals to $\dbinom{x+3}{3}$.